# get single taxonomy term from multiple selected terms

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I am facing a bit complex situation with my taxonomy terms. I have list of taxonomy terms.

```
Taxonomy (property-status):
--2018
--2019
--2020
--2021
--Coming Soon
```

my taxonomy have multiple terms, usually i select one term from the taxonomy to display which i use this code to get:

```
$status_terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'property-status');
if($status_terms) {
    foreach ( $status_terms as $term ) {
        echo $term->name;
    }
}
```

which is working perfect for me, but now i have selected two taxonomy terms `2019` and `coming soon`. If both are selected i want to show only `2019` i don't want to show `coming soon` alongside `2019`, but if only `coming soon` is selected then i want to show coming soon.

Comment: How about counting the number of terms and check if `coming-soon` is in there?

Comment: @msg Could you please explain further or if possible show me the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the terms and filter them accordingly. This might be a little bit too verbose, but may do the trick:

```
$status_terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'property-status');
if($status_terms) { 
    // Get the term names only
    $term_names = array_map(function($term) { return $term->name; }, $status_terms);
    if ((count($term_names) > 1) && in_array('coming-soon', $term_names)) {
        // More than one term and coming-soon. Filter it out
        foreach ( $status_terms as $term ) {
            if ($term->name != 'coming-soon') {
                echo $term->name;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Show everything
        foreach ( $status_terms as $term ) {
            echo $term->name;
        }
    }
}
```

Shorter solution:

```
if($status_terms) { 
  $many_terms = (count($status_terms) > 1);
  foreach ( $status_terms as $term ) {
    if ($many_terms) {
        if ($term->name != 'coming-soon') {
            echo $term->name;
        }
    } else {
        echo $term->name;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your code is working for multiple selected terms with `coming-soon` but if only coming-soon is selected it shows nothing.

Comment: @SajjadAhmad oops, missing parenthesis on the `count`. Updated answer

Comment: you are awesome @msg. works like a charm now. one thing semicolon is missing here which i add myself. `return $term->name;` but i don't want to get credit for this ;)

Comment: @SajjadAhmad thanks for the heads-up. Updated answer again.

Comment: @SajjadAhmad Alternative solution if you are interested.

Comment: thanks for posting the shorter version, I will let you once I try.